# How to extract item values from Json in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Redshift table contains 2 columns only :

```
PID str_val
1   {{"history":[{"value":"1500500.0","date":"2017-11-01"},{"value":"1614800.0","date":"2018-06-01"},{"value":"1363700.0","date":"2017-07-01"}]
2   {{"history":[{"value":"1500500.0","date":"2017-11-01"},{"value":"1614800.0","date":"2018-06-01"},{"value":"133300.0","date":"2017-07-01"}]
3   {{"history":[{"value":"1500500.0","date":"2017-11-01"},{"value":"1614800.0","date":"2018-06-01"},{"value":"1345700.0","date":"2017-07-01"}]
```

I am currently using :

```
    select json_extract_path_text(string_val, 'history','value') as key2 from property_avm_json
```

but it is not geting the value as a column. How to extract value key from this json array?
I am following the aws doc here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html

It does give me value for history alone but not with 'value' in the query? How to get this

Comment: Side-note: Storing JSON data in Amazon Redshift is very inefficient and does not benefit from the full capabilities of Redshift. If you are wishing to frequently query on individual elements, it would be advisable to convert the data into normal Redshift columns (preferably before even loading it into Redshift).

Answer (score 1):

Elements inside `[]` are an array and need to be accessed with a different function. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT.html

You can nest the functions to get the data you need

```
SELECT json_extract_path_text( 
         json_extract_array_element_text( 
           json_extract_path_text( 
             '{"history":[{"value":"1500500.0","date":"2017-11-01"},{"value":"1614800.0","date":"2018-06-01"},{"value":"1363700.0","date":"2017-07-01"}]}'
             , 'history') 
           ,1 ) 
         ,'value')  as key2 ;
--   key2
-------------
-- 1614800.0
```

Comment: How to get all the values at once? In rows